# What is the JSONAPI equivalent of Ruby on Rails Nested Attributes create/update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json-api

We are considering changing our rails app (which relies heavily on Nested Attributes-style data creation) to use JSONAPI instead. However, it seems that JSONAPI may not support this style of document creation/updating?

I've read around and this is sometimes referred to as "compound documents" or "sideposting". My research has been inconclusive, so posting here in hopes that someone out there knows the deal.

For example if in our app we had a Person that has many PhoneNumber, I would like to be able to send a PATCH to /person/1 that had information relating to phone numbers. RoR Nested Attributes allows for sending new phone numbers (ones without an id), modifying existing ones, and deleting existing ones. Is there an equivalent for this in JSONAPI?

If not, how would a client go about submitting this data to the server? A separate request for every object? On some of our pages that could result in 100 plus requests... and each one would need to be managed for errors indivdually?

Answer (score 0):

JSON:API specification v1.0 does not support to create, update or delete more than one resource with one request. So if your server only supports that version of the specification without any custom modification the client would need to submit separate requests for each resource that should be created, updated or deleted. That means the client needs to handle errors for each one individually. This may include rolling back partial changes if one requests fails in a series of related updates.

The missing support for atomic operations is known to be a problematic limitation for some use cases. It should be resolved with the [upcoming v1.1](https://github.com/json-api/json-api/issues/1435). This version is planned to add [extensions](https://jsonapi.org/format/1.1/#extensions) to the specification. An extension can extend the specification. An extension [Atomic Opersions](https://github.com/json-api/json-api/pull/1437) is proposed, which would add support for creating, updating and deleting multiple resources with one request. A client would be able to provide a list of mutations that must be processed in a linear and atomic manner by matter by a server implementing that extension. This means that the modifications are processed in order and will either completely succeed or fail together.